# get current map location when open android searchView widget

Tags: android, google-maps, searchview

Im using this code http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-actionbarcompat-library/ to use the autosearch for map positions. I would like to open the map with my current actual position. Meaning before i open my map activity i need my current location. how do i doo this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Google Map API V2 then use this method. It will display my location button on map.

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

or you can add marker on map using your current lat-long.

[API Document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

[Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Comment: nice! 1 more thing. i'd like to get my current location in an activity before the map activity is launched. Is this Possible? if yes how?